# How to print a histogram?

Tags: java, arrays, histogram

I'm trying to print a histogram, but am having trouble piecing it all together in main. I'm new to arrays, so if anyone can help with this, it'd be much appreciated. Here are my methods:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  randomIntArray(5);
}

public static int randomInt(int low, int high){
  int x= (int)(Math.random ()*high)+low;
  return x;       
}

public static int[] randomIntArray(int n){
  int[] a = new int [n];
  for (int i = 0;i<a.length;i++){
    a[i]=randomInt (0,100);
  }

  System.out.println(printHist(a));
  return a;
}

public static int[] printHist(int[]a){
  int[] k = new int[11];
  int i=0;
  while (i<=10) { 
    int counter = 0;
    int h=0;
    while(h<a.length) {
      if (a[h] == i) {
        counter++;
        h++;
      }
      h++;
    }

    k[i] = counter;
    i++;
  }

  return k;
}
```

And here's what I get as output.

```
[I@fb53f6
```

Do I need to rethink the way I'm doing this, or is there a simple fix?

Comment: Check out the `Object#toString()` method and what it does.

Comment: Try `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(printHist(a)));`

Comment: @ZouZou: Okay, it's somewhat better, but now I'm getting '[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]'.

Comment: @NickGatti Well that's another problem now. You have to investigate why.

Answer (score 0):

`System.out.println(arrayObject)` does not do what you think it does.

Try one of the solutions at this related question: [What's the simplest way to print a Java array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/409784/simplest-way-to-print-an-array-in-java) - such as `Arrays.toString(arrayObject)`

Comment: Okay, it's somewhat better, but now I'm getting '[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]'

Comment: Based on reading your code above, that sounds like `k[i] = counter` is always assigning a `0` value - possibly because either your inner while condition `h<a.length` or the if condition `a[h] == i` is not being met. Best option is to use your debugger and step through the code.